# Question about the rank-nullity theorem if the linear transformation is one to one (injective)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I have a question about my understanding of the rank-nullity theorem. Let $f: V \to W$ be a linear transformation , if I know that f is injective and that $\dim(V) = \dim (W) = 3$, I want to prove that $f$ is an isomorphism, so that it is also onto. So since $f$ is one to one, $\text{Ker}(f)= \{0\}$ so $\dim\big(\text{Ker}(f)\big)= 0$ and thus by the rank-nullity theorem, $\dim(V) = \dim\big(\text{Im}(f)\big)$. I know that $\dim\big(\text{Im}(f)\big) = 3$. At this point however, how can I connect the dimension of the Image of $f$ and that the $\dim(W) = 3$ to explain that the function onto, so that every element of $W$ is connected to a element in $V$ through $f$? I feel like they are not connected that much.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\dim W=3$, $\operatorname{Im}(f)\subset W$, and $\dim\operatorname{Im}(f)=3$, $\operatorname{Im}(f)=W$: a finite-dimensional vector space and a subspace have the same dimension if and only if they are equal.

Comment: Indeed, that is a great answer, I was just looking for a more intuitive way of thinking about the dimension and its connection with the dimension of W, without using this fact. Kind of a way to explain it to a child if you will. Still this suits my fine. Thank you!

Comment: @MorganRodgers I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $\text{Im}(f)$ is a subspace of $W$. And as you suggested, we also know that $\dim\big(\text{Im}(f)\big) = \dim(W) = 3$. This is only possible when $\text{Im}(f) = W$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer as well. As I pointed out above, I was just looking for a simpler, more intuitive way to think about this, without necessarily using linear algebra rules, just plain intuition. Thanks again though!

Comment: If $V$ and $W$ have the same dimension, then $f$ being injective means that it can't double up on anything, which means it "has to" hit everything. That's true for arbitrary functions between finite sets. The magic trick that linearity is pulling here is making it work with infinite sets.